# Small distributed database to share data across web machines

Tags: c#, distributed-caching, servicebus

I have some web server in c# that need to serve task processing over HTTP request.
the backend works on a servicebus in other machine. When I start a task via http, the task is sent over the bus and messages returning from the task returns to the webserver.

If user request task status over another machine I have to be able to get messages received from the bus in a webserver instance different from the starting one.

I think that I need some sort of distributed cache with query ability... this requirement seems to similar to a NoSql distributed database and probably RavenDb can be the right choice. But RavenDb cost seems to big for a "message cache" like the one I need.

Do you have other hint?

Answer (score 0):

How about XML and query with XPath?  Low/No cost, and works great in my distributed apps, up to 20 Mb per file.

Comment: how can I add messages to xml concurrently and distributed?

Comment: Mauro, in short you can't.  However, you could construct the cache of responses centrally (using XML), and query it with a status service to achieve the same results as distributing the information.